# Force WebView Video Controls

Tags: android, html, webview

I have an Android app that plays embedded html5 videos.  The html code that I receive does not include the "controls" attribute in the video tag.  I'm wondering if there is a way to force the controls to be shown while the video is in the WebView.  In 2.3 you can use WebChromeClient to display the full video.  However in 4.x it appears you need to show the full controls first in order to take advantage of this class.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the controls attribute:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavascriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(webView, url);
        webView.loadUrl(
            "javascript:(function() {" +
                 "var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];" +
                 "video.controls = 'controls';" +
            "})()"
        );
    }
});
```